# 1-D LDA output dimension in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to reduce dimensionality of a 2000-D data to 2D data. So I used the sample code here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html
But instead of a 2-D output I get a 1-D output from LDA. Does anyone have a suggestion for the cause?
Here is my code:

```
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
X_r2 = lda.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

The shapes of X, y, and X_r2 are as follows, respectively:

```
(33139, 2000) (33139,) (33139, 1)
```

As you see X_r2 is 1-D, wherase I expect it to be 2-D, because I have set `n_components=2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis) says, n_components is "Number of components (< n_classes - 1) for dimensionality reduction."

The parameter has no effect if it is equal to or greater than n_classes-1, because LDA will never use more dimensions than n_classes-1. The mathematical explanation is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Multiclass_LDA); informally, one dimension is enough to separate two points (thinking of classes as points now), two dimensions are enough for three points, etc.

So, if you have only two classes in your data, the output of LDA transform will be one-dimensional.

Here is a self-contained example:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
X = [[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,2,3]]
y = [0,0,0,1,1,1]
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)
print(lda.fit(X, y).transform(X))
```

The output is a 6 by 1 array. Changing `y` to

```
y = [0,0,1,1,2,2]
```

will result in 6-by-2 output.

Comment: But in my case the number of classes are 2000 not 2

Comment: That's features, not classes. The number of classes is the number of distinct entries in array `y`.